# Listening to keyboard C# (WinForm)

Tags: c#, winforms, listener, keyboard-events

I'm writing a program that I want to run when the user is "idle" (I.e. No input from the user - not moving the mouse, or typing anything). I have taken care of detecting if the mouse is moving (through storing the mouse position as a variable and comparing the current position to that variable at a later time), but what I can't figure out is how to detect keyboard input.

I know that if the user is typing in the form itself, I can use event listeners (KeyDown, KeyPressed, etc.), but I want this program to detect keyboard input anywhere on the computer, in any program.

Is there a way to accomplish this? All my research has yielded ways to check inside the form, but not globally.

Note: Not sure if this matters, but I don't care what the user is typing (what keys are being pressed). All I need to know is that there is keyboard activity.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not a direct answer to your question, but have you considered a different approach?  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3690b884-9b8a-4dbe-8c48-01e29584f201/c-application-to-detect-inactivity-in-the-system?forum=netfxbcl

Comment: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.GetLastInputInfo

Comment: To do what you're talking about, you would need to use [`SetWindowsHookEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx) with `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` (via p/invoke), but I think a better option is to use `GetLastInputInfo` as suggested by @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ

Comment: read this article [Getting the user idle time with C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13384/Getting-the-user-idle-time-with-C)

Comment: https://github.com/gmamaladze/globalmousekeyhook

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is considered a Global Keyboard Hook.

A sample with explanation and source:
[here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19004/A-Simple-C-Global-Low-Level-Keyboard-Hook)

Edit: In terms @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ answer, it would be improper to grab using GetLastInputInfo as system calls (SendInput(), keybd_event(), etc) all will trigger it as well, so that doesn't mean the user is technically there.